# ScriptBundle not rendering

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am really not sure what I have wrong

I have added a JavaScript file called `‘ListDrops-static.js’`

I have added the bundle reference

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/listdropstatic").Include(
                "~/Scripts/ListDrops-static.js"
                ));
```

and the on my _layout.cshtml I have added this

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/listdropstatic")
```

And this just isn’t working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `@Styles.Render` and not `@Scripts.Render`

this needs changing to this

```
@Scripts.Render
```